# Which version of OpenGL supports rectangular textures (w/o extensions)?

Tags: opengl, textures

Rectangular textures used to be support through extensions and at some version of OpenGL are now directly supported, i.e I can create textures with the same basic opengl methods just supplying non-power-of-two sizes.

I've googled and can't seem to find a definitive changelog for the OpenGL spec. I need this information to dynamically detect support in the application and to inform users.

Simply replying with a number like 1.5 or 3.0 isn't enough. I need a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the  [ARB_texture_non_power_of_two documentation](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/texture_non_power_of_two.txt), this extension was added as part of OpenGL 1.4.

However, it was not promoted into the core of OpenGL until OpenGL 2.0.  Any vendor implementing OpenGL 2.0 should support this fully as of OpenGL 2.0.

Comment: It's still an extension in 1.4 though.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [spec](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/version2.0/glspec20.pdf) (page 341), NPOT textures were promoted to core in OpenGL 2.0.